# Inner product on $\Bbb{R}^2$ defined using a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$, where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers.

For $x,y \in \Bbb{R}^2$ , let
$f_A(x,y) = y^T A x$ be an inner product on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Show that $b = c$ , $a > 0$ , $d > 0$ , and $ad − bc > 0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a 2x2 matrix A is symmetric positive definite if and only if A is symmetric, trace(A) > 0 and det(A) > 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173868/show-that-a-2x2-matrix-a-is-symmetric-positive-definite-if-and-only-if-a-is-symm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm right, you want to know the conditions for it to be a inner product, right? If it is, you need to show the following: Use your muscles to "math this out"!

1. ***Linearity:***

In this case, prove that
$$
f_{A}(ax,y) = a f_{A}(x,y), a \in \Bbb{R}
$$
and
$$
f_{A}(x+y,z) = f_{A}(x,z) + f_{A}(y,z).
$$

---

2. ***Symmetry***

Show that
$$
f_{A}(x,y)=f_{A}(y,x).
$$

---

3. ***"Positive-definitedness"***

Just show that, if $x \neq 0$, then
$$
f_{A}(x,x) > 0.
$$

---

While you prove this, you will be able to achieve the conditions that you want. To make it easiear, take $x = (x_{1},x_{2})$ and $y = (y_{1},y_{2})$.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks, I'll fix it.